# UIBarButtonItem with UIImage too wide

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I have a `UINavigationBar` and a `UIToolbar` (in separate views) which contain buttons and flexible space. The `UIBarButtonItems`' background is set like this:

```
bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBackgroundImage.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[self setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Within the `UINavigationBar`, the items look just fine, optimal size and all.

BUT, within the `UIToolbar`, the items are always stretched to at least the width of `bgImage` (100 points in this case):

[image]
[image]

Any ideas why, or how to solve that? Please tell me if you need more info.

Comment: maybe the flexible space is making the problems

Comment: No, checked it without the space.

Comment: Then it must be the image, you can stretch it but you cant shrink it. Use the answer @iPatel left you to resize the images before you set them on the UIToolbar. `[self setBackgroundImage:resizedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: Of course it shrinks! I'll just quote the text above: "Within the UINavigationBar, the items look just fine, optimal size and all."

Comment: Try to set a width to the bar button item, by default it's 0 and the width goes as much as the image width. I can't think of anything else

Comment: Thanks for being so persistent, but it has nothing to do with the width that is set. There must be something in the auto-resizing routine of UIToolbar vs the routine of UINavigationbar. I'll try to make the stretchable image smaller as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in UIToolbar. I gave it a try and the only "fix" that worked for me was to manually set the width of the UIBarButtonItem:

```
barButtonItem.width = 40f;
```

This will work fine for buttons with images, but not for text buttons as the size of the text may vary due to localization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method for **get/create image size** as you want.

Use following method with specific **hight** and **width** with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you specify.
And use this Image for add on `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: I am not in search of image resizing, because this is what ```resizableImageWithCapInsets:``` is for. The problem is way deeper than that, UIToolbar somehow does not compress the UIBarbuttonItem's width the way UINavigationBar does.

Comment: other option is remove fixSize of UIBarButtonItem and set each UIBarButtonItem as you want :)

Comment: AFAIK there's no way for that, but please prove me wrong. But please, don't suggest custom views.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own button with image according to your requirement

```
//  UIBarButtonItem+CutomBackground.h

+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image title:(NSString *)buttonTitle target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

//  UIBarButtonItem+CutomBackground.m

#define TEXT_MARGIN 8.0f
#define ARROW_MARGIN 12.0f
#define FONT_SIZE 13.0f
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT 31.0f

+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image title:(NSString *)buttonTitle target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{       
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:0];    
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight];
    [button setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,TEXT_MARGIN)];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:FONT_SIZE]];
    [button.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f,-1.0f)];
    CGRect buttonFrame = [button frame];
    buttonFrame.size.width = [buttonTitle sizeWithFont:[button.titleLabel font]].width+ARROW_MARGIN+TEXT_MARGIN;
    buttonFrame.size.height = IMAGE_HEIGHT;
    [button setFrame:buttonFrame];
    return [[self alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but custom button is not an option when UIToolbar should handle this wonderfully out of the box. I'd rather acknowledge this as a bug and produce a smaller stretchable image if there really is no other way.